# How to properly seal the bath tub drain?

Tags: drain, bathtub

I got this old bath tub with half broken drain flange, tried hard to get remaining piece out so I can install new one. I was able to remove it. Ready to install new bath tub shoe gasket and drain flange.

I know that drain shoe gasket seals the gap between drain shoe and tub but in order to do that job, it should stay squeezed in between the drain shoe and tub, and drain shoe can't be loose. in my case, drain shoe is moving side ways and gives in when I press a little bit, it doesn't feel like it is pressed against the tub bottom tight enough to hold new gasket in place.

What should I do? I am on 2nd floor condo.

Comment: How about a few pictures so we can see what you got.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for this:

- The replacement drain shoe is slightly taller than the original one.  IE, the center of its drain pipe is slightly farther away from the tub than before.  If you attached it to the plumbing before you attached it to the tub, it will stand proud from the tub.  Then, when you screw it down with the flange, you'll be bending it and the surrounding plumbing and it will be very hard to make good.  The solution in this case is to either find a better fitting shoe or to FIRST attach it to the tub, then cut back the old plumbing further away from the shoe and use appropriate pipe fittings to mate the misaligned pipes.
- The replacement drain shoe, gasket, and flange are not a matched set.  The flange doesn't fit properly in the shoe and won't clamp it down far enough.  The flange could be too high or the gasket could be too thin.
- You just aren't tightening enough.  Use a good bath flange wrench and get someone to hold the shoe while you tighten it.  Use thread grease on the flange if you have to.

Also, you need to put plumber's putty between the flange and the top half of the bath.  That's not the cause of this problem but I think it's worth a mention here.   Look on youtube for tutorials on how to use it.

And I'll throw in another possible cause ... hoping this is wrong:

- If you're in a second floor condo, how are you accessing the shoe?  You need to break open the ceiling below and do this properly.  I hope you aren't replacing the gasket through the drain hole and doing this blind.  If it's even possible to do that.   Just a wild and hopefully wrong guess.   This would lead you to the second of the above three explanations, but also be an explanation in itself.